# app creada con react native expo solo funciona en un dispositivo

Tags: react-native, expo

Tengo un problema, al crear mi apk con eas build puedo instalarlo en cualquier dispositivo, incluso abre mi pantalla de login, y en mi dispositivo personal, puedo iniciar sesión sin ningún problema, incluso conecta al servidor con el cual estoy trabajando (necesito conectarme al servidor mediante vpn), pero cuando inicio sesión desde cualquier otro dispositivo (También con el vpn activado), sea físico o emulado, no puedo iniciar sesión, ni si quiera realiza un intento de carga, ni me pide permisos de ubicación, como sí lo hace en mi dispositivo personal, es como si el botón de iniciar sesión no hiciera nada en los demás dispositivos.

**Captura de pantalla de app funcionando en mi dispositivo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otros dispositivos solo abre el login pero al apretar el botón de iniciar sesión no realiza nada

**app.js**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "WOSUBB",
    "slug": "WOSUBB",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "runtimeVersion": {
        "policy": "appVersion"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/LOGO.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.pablood.WOSUBB",
      "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "68..."
      }
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/68..."
    }
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RUNTIME_VERSION" android:value="@string/expo_runtime_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIza..."/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://u.expo.dev/68..."/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.pablood.WOSUBB"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**package.json**

```
"name": "wosubb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build": "expo build:android",
    "postinstall": "npx patch-package",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "npm config set legacy-peer-deps true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.2.5",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.2.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.18.12",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "iconoir-react-native": "^6.11.0",
    "lucide-react-native": "^0.268.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "phosphor-react-native": "^1.1.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1300.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-image": "^0.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Sugiero que agregues a la pregunta el procedimiento y/o la configuración de compilación, así como el logcat de la aplicación en los dispositivos que no funcionan. Creo que más conveniente mirar ahí primero.

Comment: Entiendo, he revisado varias veces en logcat pero no dice mucho, el error que arroja es este `Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0` aun así adjuntare pantallazos del logcat. También, he estado pensado y puede que sea que el servidor al que me conecto es http y no https, estoy creando una nueva apk para ver si lo solucioné.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya esta solucionado, el problema era que al servidor que se conecta mi aplicación era http y desde android 9 ya no se soporta nativamente http, por lo que tuve que modificar el AndroidManifest poniendo `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` en la etiqueta de `<application/>`, y también, en mi caso, usar `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RUNTIME_VERSION" android:value="@string/expo_runtime_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIz..."/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://u.expo.dev/68..."/>
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.pablood.WOSUBB"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```