# Apk expo, api rest no funciona

Tags: fetch, expo, apk

Cuando ejecuto mi codigo en la app de expo con QR funciona todo bien, pero cuando descargo el apk, no hace llamadas http a una api externa

Comment: Bienvenido, pueden ser varias las causas, agrega el código donde haces uso de la API por favor, revisar [ask].

Comment: al principio probe con una dependencia de la api...la api en cuestion es frappe framework...pide loguearse con un token y luego tenes acceso a la base de dato .. Me logueo, y hago todos los pedidos correspodientes. En expo funciona y en apk no....luego hice todo igual sin usar la dependencia de frappe...lo hice por fetch direecto y lo mismo, en expo funciona y en apk no....en frappe cambie el cors a "*" para no tener problemas pero nada

Comment: const doctypeCall = (doctype, options, setter) => {
        fetch(`${url}/api/resource/${doctype}?${options}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `token ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(r => {
                setter(r.data)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }

Comment: Aca en este post que estuve mirando esta la respuesta... por lo menos a mi me funciono:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/603650/342645

Comment: Estoy con expo, no tengo ese archivo de androidManifest..o es es desde mi telefono?